# Is it possible to create a drywall ceiling around pipes?

Tags: drywall, ceiling

I have a basement which I want to soundproof using drywall but I have a problem with some pipes in the ceiling that run around the corners. I want to maximize the space in the room after soundproofing so I wanted to know if it is possible to do something like this. (please see image, the circles are the pipes in the corners)

[image]

Comment: You mean oversized trim to cover the pipes? Sure that's possible.

Comment: You could build a soffit around the pipes. I had to do this in the middle of my basement where the pipes and HVAC were.

Comment: @Ratchet I did a search to learn how this is done but nothing comes up under "oversized trim". What is this type of drywall construction normally called?

Comment: @Dragon: What did you build the soffit out of?

Comment: @armand 'Coving' is another possible term for 'trim'.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a soffit out of 2x4s (or 2x2s) and screws. Once it is complete, you can wrap it in drywall like any other wall. The boards that touch the external wall may need to by pressure treated (check your local codes).